# How to set up on-disk cache for a Squid cache server?

Tags: ubuntu, cache, squid

I want to build an Ubuntu-based cache server, using Squid, and I need an on-disk cache up to 65GB.

1. How much RAM do I need for this?
2. Is it a better practice to divide the 65GB to 5 or 10GB cache
   directories, will it enhance the performance to some extent?

Comment: You're asking a very broad question. Please ask only *one question at a time*, especially the third one and the fourth one. I'd recommend taking them out here, and posting [a new one](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) for each.

Comment: on i am going to do this